# How to save and restore the browser selection with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selection

I am using a library that uses a hidden input element as a side effect. This causes the browser selection to be lost when activated. How do I save the current selection and restore it after the (synchronous) action is complete? I would like to know how to do this in vanilla Javascript if possible.

```js
// how to save the selection?

doSomethingThatUsesHiddenInput() // removes the selection

// how to restore the selection?
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566611/how-can-i-save-and-restore-selection-range-in-javascript That question calls for serialization, though (e.g., to string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) to get a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object, which contains the ranges of selected content. Most browsers support only a single range in a selection created by users interacting with the page (multiple if done programmatically), but Gecko-based browsers such as Firefox allow users to create multiple ranges by holding down Ctrl while selecting, or by Ctrl-clicking table cells to select them.

Saving:

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
const savedRanges = [];
for (let i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {
    savedRanges.push(selection.getRangeAt(i));
}
```

Restoring:

Unfortunately, Firefox has odd behavior when you use Ctrl-click to select table cells *and* then hold down Ctrl to select text is other elements as well. We have to work around that to make this work reliably on Firefox by restoring the table cell ones (`startContainer.nodeName` is `"TR"`) first, then the others; see below.

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
for (const range of savedRanges.filter(({startContainer: {nodeName}}) => nodeName === "TR")) {
    selection.addRange(range);
}
for (const range of savedRanges.filter(({startContainer: {nodeName}}) => nodeName !== "TR")) {
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const plural = (singular, plural) =>
    (number) =>
        `${number} ${number === 1 ? singular : plural}`;
const ranges = plural("range", "ranges");

document.querySelector(".hover").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    // Save selection
    console.log(`Saving selection...`);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const savedRanges = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < selection.rangeCount; ++i) {
        savedRanges.push(selection.getRangeAt(i));
    }
    
    // Remove it and report
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    console.log(`${ranges(savedRanges.length)} saved and removed.`);
    
    // Restore it after a moment
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Restoring ${ranges(savedRanges.length)}...`);
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        // To support unusual Firefox behavior around a mix of selections
        // inside and outside tables, restore ranges whose start container
        // is TR first, then others
        for (const range of savedRanges.filter(({startContainer: {nodeName}}) => nodeName === "TR")) {
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
        for (const range of savedRanges.filter(({startContainer: {nodeName}}) => nodeName !== "TR")) {
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
        console.log(`Done`);
    }, 800);
});
```

```css
.hover {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>
Select text in the document, then move your mouse over the <strong>Hover to Run</strong> box below but <strong>don't</strong> click it (because that would remove your selection). The action will happen when your mouse enters the <strong>Hover to Run</strong> area. On Firefox, try doing multiple selections by holding down Ctrl when selecting, or by Ctrl-clicking table cells.
</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>three</td>
            <td>four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>five</td>
            <td>six</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hover">Hover to Run</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The suggested ways of saving the selection will not properly restore the selection when it is backward (when the "focus" position is before the "anchor" position). The following solves this.

```
function saveSelection() {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    return [selection.anchorNode, selection.anchorOffset, selection.focusNode, selection.focusOffset];
}

function restoreSelection(saved) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.setBaseAndExtent(saved[0], saved[1], saved[2], saved[3]);
}
```

Comment: But unlike T.J. Crowder's answer this doesn't work if there is more than one selected range. Is there any approach that works in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Browser Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and restore the selection range:

```js
// save the selection
const sel = window.getSelection()
const range = sel?.rangeCount > 0 ? sel?.getRangeAt(0) : null

doSomethingThatUsesHiddenInput() // removes the selection

// restore the selection
if (range) {
  sel?.removeAllRanges()
  sel?.addRange(range)
}
```